# Data lost in the postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a way for a piece of data to presist across postbacks. Is there a way besides, cookies, and sessions?

I've got a listbox, when clicked, the selected index changed event takes a session which contains user id and feeds it to a method that fetches user's name, etc. Then I use FindControl method to locate a button inside the form view. I set the button's text property with data just fetched such as first and last name.

It works on the initial load, but if I click on other records in the listbox second time the text property is not set.

I did not write this code - I'm trying to make chages.

Here is the list box:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbxUpcommingEvents" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsUpcommingEvents" 
Rows="6" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="true"
Width="206px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lbxUpcommingEvents_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  />
```

Listbox'x on selected index changed:

```
protected void lbxUpcommingEvents_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlEventsSignUp.Visible = true;
    string _selectedItemValue = lbxUpcommingEvents.SelectedValue.ToString();

    LoadName();

}

protected void LoadName()
{
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
    DataSetTableAdapters.MemberInfoTableAdapter da = new DataSetTableAdapters.MemberInfoTableAdapter();

    Guid _memberId = Guid.Empty;
    _memberId = new Guid(Session["myId"].ToString());
    DataSet.MemberInfoDataTable dt = da.GetMember(_memberId);
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        DataSet.MemberInfoRow mr = dt[0];

        RolloverLink rlnkSignUp = (RolloverLink)(fvEventSignUp.FindControl("rlnkSignUp"));
        rlnkSignUp.Text = "I, " + mr.firstname + " " + mr.lastname + " will be attending this event.";
    }
}
```

Here is markup for the form view where I set the RolloverLinkButton's text property.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlEventsSignUp" visible="false">
<div class="dashedline" ></div>
<asp:FormView ID="fvEventSignUp" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    DataKeyNames="id" Width="100%" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h2>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' runat="server" ID="titleLabel" />
        </h2>
        <div class="itemdetails">
            <br />
            location:
            <h3>
                <asp:Label ID="locationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# ShowLocationLink(Eval("locationname"),Eval("location")) %>' />
            </h3>
            <p>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("starttime","{0:D}") %>' runat="server" ID="itemdateLabel" CssClass="GeneralText" />

                <asp:Label Text='<%# ShowDuration(Eval("starttime"),Eval("endtime")) %>' runat="server" ID="Label1"  CssClass="GeneralText" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="downloadevent">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/icon_download_event.gif" alt="Download this event to your personal calendar"
                    width="15" height="26" /></a><a href='<%# "events_download.ashx?EventID=" + Convert.ToString(Eval("id")) %>'>Add
                        this event to your personal calendar</a>
        </div>
        <Club:ImageThumbnail ID="thumb1" runat="server" ImageSize="Large" PhotoID='<%# Eval("photo") %>' />
        <p>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' runat="server" ID="descriptionLabel" />
        </p>
        <div class="dashedline" ></div>
        <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" CssClass="actionbuttons" Visible='<%#User.IsInRole("Administrators") %>'>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text="Action<br />Required" Width="80px" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/RedArrow.jpg" alt="Red Arrow Right" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbxCert" Height="30px" Text="Check to Confirm Attendance" /><br />
                        <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="rfvConfirm" 
                                    ErrorMessage="You must check the box to continue" Font-Bold="true"
                                    ForeColor="#cc0000" ClientValidationFunction="ensureChecked" /> <br />
                        <Club:RolloverLink ID="rlnkSignUp" runat="server"
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>                    
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: FormsView does not retain data on postbacks, or for that matter databound controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ViewState.  Since you are dynamically looking up the button, setting a property is quicker and we can then let Asp.Net **find** the button and set its text via one of the two methods I explain below:

```
public string rlnkSignUpText
{
    get { return Convert.ToString(ViewState["rlnkSignUpText"] ?? "default value"); }
    set { ViewState["rlnkSignUpText"] = value; }
}
```

Replace your code that searches for the button and assigns the text with:

```
rlnkSignUpText = "I, " + mr.firstname + " " + mr.lastname + " will be attending this event.";
```

Then use one of these methods to **set** the text to the control:

**1) Use the control's OnPreRender event:**

To render it, add `OnPreRender="rlnkSignUp_PreRender"` to your xaml like this:

```
<Club:RolloverLink ID="rlnkSignUp" runat="server" OnPreRender="rlnkSignUp_PreRender" />
```

Then in your codebehind:

```
protected void rlnkSignUp_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RolloverLink rlnkSignUp = (RolloverLink)sender;
    rlnkSignUp.Text = rlnkSignUpText;
}
```

**2) Bind the property and control together:**

Instead of using the control's PreRender you can bind to the property with:

```
<Club:RolloverLink ID="rlnkSignUp" runat="server" Text='<%# rlnkSignUpText %>' />
```

You then need to call `DataBind` in your `Page_PreRender()` like so:

```
void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what sort of magic this is and I really thank you bigtime!!! Needless to say I've plugged it in and it works beautifully. I feel like I was handed a fish rather than tought how to fish. If you have any resources that detail how this works I sure would appreciate it. Again, many thanks!

Comment: ViewState is data that 'stays with the page' between postbacks.  How it works, is the data is encrypted/compressed and passed back and forth from user to server. Because of this, ViewState can't be trusted 100%, because users technically could modify it.  Use session for stuff that must not be tampered with, but that uses server memory. ViewState can hold any object that can be serialized.  You can do a google on ViewState for more information.  You can see your page's ViewState information by looking at the page's source via your browser.

Comment: PreRender is the event that is used to do any last chance modifications to a control/the page before the page is rendered.  So that is the ideal place to put data into a control.  The `DataBind()` does just that, it loops through all the controls on the page and bind's any data as I showed in `2`.  You could do the OnPreRender for the control, and instead of setting the data as in `1` do a `rlnkSignUp.DataBind()` but that's a little excessive in my opinion and the reason I didn't list it, since setting the data at that point made sense.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled ViewState in the control.

[Enable View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx)